# Deleting a working app from iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

We have a partner that is actually owning our app on it's iTunes Connect account. We are actually developping the v2 of this app which will be included in our iTunes Connect account, it's the same app, just a new release.

Actually the app is at "removed from sales" status in our partner iTunes Connect account and people who have the app can still use it, everything is OK.

But we can't reuse the same app name in our iTunes Connect because the app name is already in use.

So, we are asking our partner to completly delete the app, then we can use the name & publish our own app. The question is :

**If our partner completly delete the app, will it continue to work on every user devices?**

I already looked at the iTunes developer guide, but it's not really clear, and Apple doesn't answer clearly too ..

```
Deleting an App If you have created an app in iTunes Connect that you no longer need to see or manage, you can delete it from your iTunes Connect view.

IMPORTANT: Deleting your app will not allow you to reuse your SKU or App Name in the same account again and you will not be able to restore your app once deleted. If you have uploaded a binary or set up this app for the iAd Network, your Bundle ID will not be reusable either.

If you are selling your app to another developer for their own distribution and need to remove it from your iTunes Connect account, we recommend that you use App Delete so the App Name will be freed up for their use.
```

So, does someone already deleted (not removed from sales) an app from the iTunes Connect ?
Does the app is still working on devices ?

Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will continue to work on the users phone's, but they will not be able to install your app again from iCloud.

Comment: Yes once. The app is still on my iPad but not available in the store any more.

Comment: And what about save, backup etc ? That's the same as iCloud ? That means, if the user is backing up his phone, no more app ?

Comment: I've not yet upgrade my iPad to iOS 5, so can't tell you if it would remove the app. But I don't think it will. Image you bought an app, paid some money for it and then it got removed by the developer? That would not be fair. I don't think that you can force delete an app from you device this way.

Comment: You could al ways ask this question on the Apple support forum. You are most likely to get a correct answer there.